# C++ Error: “expression must have integral or unscoped enum type” when inserting element into std::map with operator[]

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

There are a lot of questions with this title but it seems neither of them is similar to my case.

I have a class member

```
std::map<std::string, Mode> m_stringToMode;
```

`Mode` is

```
enum class Mode
{
    Default, Express
};
```

And a I have a `const` method where I have inserted a new element into my map with `operator[]`

```
void LevelParser::myFunc() const
{
    std::string myStr = "myStr";
    m_stringToMode[myStr] = Mode::Express;
}
```

And I got 2 errors

1. `C2678: binary '[' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::map<std::string,Mode,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`
2. `C++ Error: “expression must have integral or unscoped enum type”`

After some time of debugging I have find out that I did stupid thing trying  to modify member variable inside const member function.

So my question is. Is there any connection with error messages I have got and mistake I have did? Why compiler rising this error for this case?

I am compiling my code on Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Either make the function non-const, or `m_stringToMode` `mutable`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖI do not ask how to solve the issue. I am trying to understand the error message I have got.

Comment: The full error message, along with indicating on which line it occurs, would help.

Comment: @TM That's why I commented, instead of writing this as an answer.

Comment: @Angew I have got  error C2678: binary '[' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::map<std::string,Mode,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: If you edit the question to clarify that you're actually getting two errors, and in what order, it will become an upvotable SO question, I'd say.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have modified text, I think this part of my question ,`I want to insert` , your `Either make the function non-const, or m_stringToMode mutable` comment refer to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the first error is clear: inside a `const`-qualified member function, all non-`mutable` data members of the object are accessed through a `const`-qualified access path. So your map is effectively `const` and you're trying to call a non-`const` function on it.

As for the exact wording of the first error: remember that `std::map::operator[]` is pretty much a function like any other. You're calling it with arguments of type `const std::map` and `std::string`. The compiler is saying it couldn't find any overload which could accept them. Of course, the reason is that the only existing overload requires a non-`const` `map`.

The second error you're getting can simply be ignored. The compiler is somewhat confused by the first error and prints the spurious second one.

What probably happens is that the compiler says "you cannot use `map`'s `operator []` here, it's non-`const` and your map is `const`." Then, since it didn't find an operator overload for `[]`, it interprets it as the built-in operator `[]`, for which at least one operand must have integral or unscoped enumeration type. Hence the second error.

Comment: but my map is not constant. You wrote `and your map is const.`

Comment: @TM It is, effectively, since you're in a `const` funciton. I've clarified the answer.

Comment: Actually I have expected something like this
`error C3490: 'someVar' cannot be modified because it is being accessed through a const object` for this case. 

So I got  `C2678: binary '['`, and navigate to line and saw `“expression must have integral or unscoped enum type”`, which confused me as this insertion was valid. Thanks for explanations.

Comment: @TM You effectively got "Cannot be modified because it's `const`," albeit in more convoluted (and more exact) terms. `std::map::operator[]` is effectively a function like any other. You're calling it with arguments of type `const std::map` and `std::string`. The compiler is saying it couldn't find any overload which could accept them. Of course, the reason is that the only existing overload requires a non-`const` `map`.

Comment: Thank you one more time for explanations. Hopefully my case will help others to shorten debugging time.